# Send-MailMessage subject "k"

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with subject of "Send-MailMessage".

```
Send-MailMessage -to $to -from "test@test2.com" -subject "Book TEST" -body "test" -SmtpServer $emailSMTP
```

=> This don't work

```
Send-MailMessage -to $to -from "test@test2.com" -subject "Booo TEST" -body "test" -SmtpServer $emailSMTP
```

=> This work

Can you tell me why with the "k" it don't work??

Comment: Can you elaborate on "This don't work" - do you get an error? Does the email end up in your spam filter? This is probably not so much an issue with the cmdlet but with the delivery path of the mail

Comment: Sorry I had a filter on my webmail... it's work.